# Call stored closure from an async closure in rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-futures

I have a closure that mutates variables designed outside of it. How would I go about calling this closure that modifies the state from inside an async scope?

I have the following code (abstracted, to show the issue):

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut y = false;

    let mut incr = |z: bool| {
        y = z;
    };

    stream::iter(0..1).for_each(|_| async {
        incr(true);
    }).await;
});
```

Which produces the following:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/main.rs:40:37
   |
36 |       let mut incr = |z: bool| {
   |           -------- variable defined here
...
40 |       stream::iter(0..1).for_each(|_| async {
   |  ___________________________________-_^
   | |                                   |
   | |                                   inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
41 | |         incr(true);
   | |         ---- variable captured here
42 | |     }).await;
   | |_____^ returns an `async` block that contains a reference to a captured variable, which then escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

Now, I believe I understand why the error is occurring. I just cannot figure out a way around this.

For context:

1. I have a websocket client and I am reading from the stream
2. Every time I receive data from the stream, I am transforming it
3. I then need to call a closure with the transformed data to be used elsewhere - essentially like an EventEmitter in JavaScript.

Am I going about this the wrong way? I am a JavaScript developer, so I'm having to change my way of thinking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rust, usually, you need to use some kind of synchronization mechanisms. It would be really difficult to send a reference to a normal variable. So you would need to use some `Arc`, `RwLock`, `Mutex` depending on your needs. Also you will probably want to `move` them into the closure to avoid lifetimes problems.

In this case I think `Arc<Cell>` would do:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::sync::Arc;
use futures::StreamExt;
use futures::stream;


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let yy = Arc::new(Cell::new(false));
    let y = yy.clone();
    let incr = move |z: bool| {
        y.set(z);
    };

    stream::iter(0..1).for_each(|_| async {
        incr(true);
    }).await;
    
    println!("{yy:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f856e74b05b02da388550e0a6dd790f)

Check out the [`sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/) for further reading.
As well as [`cell` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html)

Comment: This did indeed work for my application, thanks. I'll read up on cell more.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to clone the arc for being moved to a new closure, rather than having to define a new clone for each closure that it is moved to?

Comment: It is usually preferred to write `let y = Arc::clone (&yy);` to make it clear that you are cloning the `Arc` and not the `Cell<bool>` it contains (which also [implements `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#impl-Clone)).

Comment: Thanks @Jmb. I did see that in the documentation and personally prefer that also.